# Как сгруппировать столбец по минутной компоненте времени?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных, временные-ряды

Есть временной ряд в формате DataFrame. Col1-Даты с шагом в 15 мин ,Col2-значения по этим датам.

Я хочу получить 4 новых DataFrame:

1. В DataFrame1 в col1 будут только даты с значением минут 00. Например, (01.01.2018 00:00, 01.01.2018 01:00,...)
2. В DataFrame2 в col1 будут только даты со значением минут 15.Например, (01.01.2018 00:15, 01.01.2018 01:15,...)
3. В DataFrame3 в col1 будут только даты со значением минут 30.Например, (01.01.2018 00:30, 01.01.2018 01:30,...)
4. В DataFrame4 в col1 будут только даты со значением минут 45.Например, (01.01.2018 00:45, 01.01.2018 01:45,...)

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшой пример входных и выходных данных. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'col1':pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='15 min', periods=100), 
  'col2':np.random.randint(100, size=(100))
}).sample(frac=1)
```

---

```
In [124]: df
Out[124]:
                  col1  col2
51 2018-01-01 12:45:00    84
72 2018-01-01 18:00:00     2
47 2018-01-01 11:45:00     2
67 2018-01-01 16:45:00    35
9  2018-01-01 02:15:00     9
..                 ...   ...
79 2018-01-01 19:45:00     2
18 2018-01-01 04:30:00    47
98 2018-01-02 00:30:00     5
17 2018-01-01 04:15:00    19
21 2018-01-01 05:15:00    81

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Решение:

```
d = {minute:x for minute,x in df.groupby(df.col1.dt.minute)}
```

Результат:

```
In [126]: d.keys()
Out[126]: dict_keys([0, 15, 30, 45])

In [127]: d[0]
Out[127]:
                  col1  col2
72 2018-01-01 18:00:00     2
44 2018-01-01 11:00:00    79
32 2018-01-01 08:00:00    52
20 2018-01-01 05:00:00    78
16 2018-01-01 04:00:00    87
..                 ...   ...
92 2018-01-01 23:00:00    53
8  2018-01-01 02:00:00    56
40 2018-01-01 10:00:00    51
84 2018-01-01 21:00:00    72
88 2018-01-01 22:00:00    24

[25 rows x 2 columns]

In [128]: d[15]
Out[128]:
                  col1  col2
9  2018-01-01 02:15:00     9
65 2018-01-01 16:15:00    70
53 2018-01-01 13:15:00    55
49 2018-01-01 12:15:00     9
85 2018-01-01 21:15:00    18
..                 ...   ...
77 2018-01-01 19:15:00    79
97 2018-01-02 00:15:00    42
5  2018-01-01 01:15:00    63
17 2018-01-01 04:15:00    19
21 2018-01-01 05:15:00    81

[25 rows x 2 columns]
```